# javascript: push array values from string variable

Tags: javascript

So as the title says, I'm trying to set an array from a string variable.

```
/*** THIS DOES NOT WORK ***/
var Multi = [];
var test = "[0,1],[1,5],[2,3],[3,10]";
Multi.push(test);


/*** THIS WORKS ***/
var Multi = [];
Multi.push([0,1],[1,5],[2,3],[3,10]);
```

Why is it that when I save it as a string it doesn't work? I need for it to work in a string as I'm pulling these values from another PHP file via AJAX.

Thanks.

Comment: When it's "inside" a string, it's just a string. It would be completely crazy for JavaScript to peek inside every string to find out whether there's a way to parse it. In your case, you don't even have a valid JSON structure.

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve this manually?

Comment: The best thing would be to make sure the server side prepares a clean JSON structure for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert your string to valid JSON by adding `[` to the front and `]` to the back, and then use `JSON.parse()` to convert your JSON string to an array.  Now that you have an array from you string you can extend the `Multi` array using `Multi.push.apply(Multi, array)` as shown below:

```
var Multi = [];
var test = "[0,1],[1,5],[2,3],[3,10]";
Multi.push.apply(Multi, JSON.parse('[' + test + ']'));
```

As mentioned in comments, a cleaner approach would be to make sure that your PHP file generates valid JSON.  All of this answer would be the same except that you wouldn't need to manually add the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

### [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Make the server send JSON instead of an arbitrary data format so you have the following:

```
var response = "[[0,1],[1,5],[2,3],[3,10]]"; // JSON data coming as string from somewhere
Multi = JSON.parse(response);
```

(Documentation of [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse))

### [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Split the string at pattern instances, if you only ever receive arrays of arrays of numbers or other nicely behaving data:

```
var response = "[0,1],[1,5],[2,3],[3,10]"; // string coming from somewhere
Multi = response.split(/\s*\]\s*,\s*\[\s*/).map(
    function(s) {
        return s.split(/\s*,\s*/).map(parseInt);
    });
```

Comment: second method will keep numbers as string.

Comment: Thanks. I included that in my answer. It also doesn't strip away the leading and trailing brackets, but the reader should get the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the AJAX input that you're reading, you could try:

```
var Multi = [],
    test = "0,1|1,5|2,3|3,10",
    groups = test.split('|');

for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    var tmpArray = groups[i].split(',');
    Multi.push(tmpArray);
}
```